# Using Python Requests to acces apsis API - how to it the requested data correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Ive been trying to acces the apsis api using the python requests module;
http://se.apidoc.anpdm.com/Browse/Method/MailingListService/CreateMailinglist

Ive in the past been able to pass the apsis api my api key and get the the entirety of the accounts mailing lists
http://se.apidoc.anpdm.com/Browse/Method/MailingListService/GetAllMailingLists

however im experiencing problems passing the api the requestbody parameters, i can see that it authenticates correctly but it also returns a bad input (400) when i try to pass it the data
My code currently;

```
import requests
import csv
import json
import os
API_KEY ="ThEApiKeyGoEsHerE"

headers = {
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'User-Agent':'ApsisRestClient- ver1.0.0.0 (Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0)',
    'Authorization':'Basic NmJhMzIxYTEtZjUxNi00ZGZkLWFiMmYtNGYyOWQzYTExYmY2Og==',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate',
    'Host':'se.api.anpdm.com'
}
theRead = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "tester.txt","r", newline='')
message = theRead.read().splitlines()
params= dict(
        CharacterSet= message[0],
        Description= message[1],
        FolderID= message[2],
        FromEmail= message[3],
        FromName= message[4],
        Name= message[5],
        ReplyToEmail= message[6]
        )
params=json.dumps(params)
params=json.loads(params)


r = requests.post('http://se.api.anpdm.com/v1/mailinglists/', headers=headers ,data={'username' : API_KEY, 'password' : ''}, params=params)
print(r.status_code)
```

I have also tried in a variety of other ways;

```
r = requests.post('http://se.api.anpdm.com/v1/mailinglists/', headers=headers ,data={'username' : API_KEY, 'password' : ''}, json=params)
```

And:

```
params={
    "CharacterSet": message[0],
    "Description": message[1],
    "FolderID": message[2],
    "FromEmail": message[3],
    "FromName": message[4],
    "Name": message[5],
    "ReplyToEmail": message[6]
}
```

and

```
r = requests.post('http://se.api.anpdm.com/v1/mailinglists/', headers=headers, data={'username' : API_KEY, 'password' : '', "FromEmail": message[3], "FromName": message[4], "Name": message[5]})
```

Can anyone help me make sense of how im supposed to pass their api this extra data?
I have also tried to include the extra data in the header aswell but to now avail.

i have now tried the following edits;

```
data= {
        'CharacterSet': message[0],
        'Description': message[1],
        'FolderID': message[2],
        'FromEmail': message[3],
        'FromName': message[4],
        'Name': message[5],
        'ReplyToEmail': message[6],
        'username' : API_KEY,
        'password' : ''
        }




r = requests.post('http://se.api.anpdm.com/v1/mailinglists/', json.dumps(data), headers=headers )
print(r.status_code)
```

i have also tried with above code

```
r = requests.post('http://se.api.anpdm.com/v1/mailinglists/', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers )
print(r.status_code)
```

**SOLUTION FOUND:**
Alright folks ive figured out the problem;
the api sends you neet usefull information if you include the following code at the end of the script;

```
print(r.text)
```

turns out i was trying to pass the api an invalid email and it did not enjoy that..
code that works for those wanting to use this api similarly;

```
import requests
import csv
import json
import os
API_KEY ="ThEApiKeyGoEsHerE"

headers = {
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'User-Agent':'ApsisRestClient- ver1.0.0.0 (Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0)',
    'Authorization':'Basic NmJhMzIxYTEtZjUxNi00ZGZkLWFiMmYtNGYyOWQzYTExYmY2Og==',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate',
    'Host':'se.api.anpdm.com'
}
theRead = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "tester.txt","r", newline='')
message = theRead.read().splitlines()
data= {
        'CharacterSet': message[0],
        'Description': message[1],
        'FolderID': message[2],
        'FromEmail': message[3],
        'FromName': message[4],
        'Name': message[5],
        'ReplyToEmail': message[6],
        'username' : API_KEY,
        'password' : ''
        }




r = requests.post('http://se.api.anpdm.com/v1/mailinglists/', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers )
print(r.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

For POST request using requests package in python the correct structure is

```
requests.post(url, json.dumps(data), headers)
```

just create one dictionary for all the data that is to be posted and convert it to JSON string before posting.

Comment: Well i have now included the extra requestbody material in the data container but still the dreaded error code 400

i have included this in the main post

including also the headers in data yielded not authorized error code (401)